# Java API to tag TIFF files

Tags: java, tiff

Is there an open source Java API to tag TIFF image files?

Comment: There is a tool [here](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe/blob/master/src/com/icafe4j/image/tiff/TIFFImage.java) I created as part of a larger image library [icafe](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe/wiki) which can be used to manipulate single or multipage TIFF images.

Comment: There is also a [test](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe/blob/master/src/com/icafe4j/test/TestTIFFImage.java) for the above tool.

Comment: Be warned, there is a great chance the image will be ruined if some critical tags are changed.

Answer (score 4):

I think that Apache Commons Sanselan may meet your needs

http://commons.apache.org/imaging/

Comment: Perfect! this is exactly what I needed! JAI-IO was not desirable, as it is not "automatically" cross platform.

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with the project.

Comment: Actually, I jumped the gun - I can fetch all tags, but not update them. I contacted the project owners, and have been informed that while JPEGs tags can be updated, TIFF cannot (at the moment). so its back to the drawing board for me :(

Comment: Sorry about that... I didn't know about the TIFF limitation.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the Java 2D API to manipulates a variety of images and draw graphics.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/index.html